# AfterDelConfirm event not triggering Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two subforms each representing a table in my database. These subforms display all the records in those tables and they have a 1 to many relationship between each other.

When a record is deleted in the parent subform, it deletes all the children in the other one (I have cascade delete on).

I need to do some handling in the child form once the deletion is complete. I would like to use the AfterDelConfirm event but I cannot get it to fire.

I do not even get an option to confirm the delete (in the parent form). In fact I am doing it manually:

```
  Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
     Dim PhaseID As Long
     Dim Response As Long
     Dim style As Long
     style = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
     Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete this phase and all related scenarios and nodes?", style)
     If Response = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
     End If
  End Sub
```

Trying to get this to run:

```
  Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
     Debug.Print "trigger plz"
  End Sub
```

Is there a way I can get this event to fire with the way I have things set up?

Comment: When you say "I do not even get an option to confirm the delete", you mean in the child form? Child form events won't trigger if you delete from the Main (active) form.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want the Parent form's AfterDelConfirm to trigger. I do not get an option to confirm the delete when deleting records in the Parent form. Right now I am manually doing it with the Respone = MsgBox("...") line

Comment: You say you have 2 subforms. is it really 2 subforms or is it a form with a subform? if it's 2 subforms, can you explain?

Comment: If it is 2 subforms, can you rework it so the parent data is in the form, and the child data is in a subform?

Comment: Yeah they are two subforms that reside within the main form and exist on the same layer. It is possible for me to do that but the entire program is already written so it would be cumbersome to adjust the rest of the program accordingly.

Comment: How are you deleting records? Are you using the normal GUI (click record selector, hit delete key?)

Comment: If you are deleting records from subforms in a main form, events of subforms won't trigger unless you use what @ErikvonAsmuth says. My guess is that you delete with VBA records in subforms but you do it from main form, so those confirms won't trigger never ever

Comment: So only the main form can trigger after delete events?? That seems rather short-sighted. And yeah I am using the normal GUI, record selector of the subform to delete a record within the same subform. I do get an onDelete event but not an on AfterDeleteConfirm event.